# I can't activate my virtual environment in pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I just made a virtual environment but trying to open it with

> mypython\Scripts\activate

Can anybody tell me why this is not working?

[image]

Comment: PyCharm -> Preferences -> Project -> Python Interpreter -> Gear icon -> Add -> Existing environment. You want to setup venv for your IDE, not just a terminal. After you do that restart PyCharm.

Comment: From the directory of your environment you need to do: "source venv/bin/activate"

Comment: But if I go there how do I select the mypython virtual environment? I can't open it as a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the picture you are actually trying with 'mypthon' and not 'mypython'. But as i understand it, the virtual environment you're trying to activate in your picture is actually in a folder called 'venv' and not 'mypython'. Therefore i think it could be that you instead should write

> venv\Scripts\activate